# Can call JavaScript function from Keys.onPressed handler, but not from Shortcuts onActivated handler. Why?

Tags: qt, qml

This is an except from my code:

```
Keys.onPressed: {
    if ((event.modifiers & Qt.AltModifier) && (event.modifiers & Qt.ControlModifier) && event.key === Qt.Key_Plus) {
        zoom(true, false);
    }
    if ((event.modifiers & Qt.AltModifier) && (event.modifiers & Qt.ControlModifier) && event.key === Qt.Key_Minus) {
        zoom(false, false);
    }
}

Shortcut {
    id: zoomInX
    sequence: StandardKey.ZoomIn
    onActivated: {
        zoom(true, true);
    }
}

Shortcut {
    id: zoomOutX
    sequence: StandardKey.ZoomOut
    onActivated: {
        zoom(true, false);
    }
}

function zoom(zoomIn, zoomX) {
    ...
}
```

The `zoom` function can be called just fine from the Keys.onPressed code.

But when the `zoom` function is called from the Shortcut's `onActivated` code I get the following message:

> ... W: unknown: ... ReferenceError: zoom is not defined

Why is this? How can I fix it?

I would have imagined that since the zoom function is available to the Keys item it would also be available to the `Shortcut` item, and via closure also available to the `onActivated` code.

From the docs:

> In QML, component instances connect their component scopes together to
>   form a scope hierarchy. Component instances can directly access the
>   component scopes of their ancestors.

http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qdeclarativescope.html

Comment: Apparently it works if I write ancestorItemName.zoom. I still am not sure why I need to do this. Does QML automatically set functions to be properties of the JavaScript representation of the QML objects in which they are defined?

Comment: yes QML does automaticaly set functions to be part of the QML object it is defined in

Answer (score 1):

As you indicate you must use the ancestor's id to identify the function, in case the function is called in the scope of the ancestor the id can be omitted. These are necessary as indicated for the identification since each item can define functions with the same name.

Comment: In JavaScript this would be solved with shadowing. I have found in the QML documentation that JavaScript functions declared in QML items are actually saved as methods on those items: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#method-attributes. This solves the confusion for me.